# How to upload image from <image src> tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a image tag on a webpage as below.

```
<image src='http://xxxxxx.jpg'/>
```

Now I want to get that image and upload it to a remote http server in javascript. 
The value of the image url is variable defined in javascript which is from a http API call. I want to upload that image to a remote server like below. How can I set the value on 'HOW_TO_SET_THIS_VALUE' in this case?

```
axios({
    url: backendServerAddress + '/user/upload_photo',
    method: 'post',
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
      'ACCESS_TOKEN': token
    },
    data:  HOW_TO_SET_THIS_VALUE,
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('update photo response '+ response)

  }).catch(response=>{
    console.log('failed to upload photo')

  })
```

Comment: You can right click on the image and save it? You need to be more specific about context.

Comment: why not just save the link at server

Comment: @AnmolMittal The link may not be accessible from internet. So I need to upload the image to a remote server instead of a link.

Comment: Use ajax call to retrieve data from image url

Answer (score 0):

```
var filedata = document.getElementById('#IdOfYourFileInputElement').files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name_offile_field_of_your_choice',filedata);
formData.append('some_field_other_than_file',valueOfThatField);

var HOW_TO_SET_THIS_VALUE = formData;
```

After this do the request to server as you are doing then
At server side you can access it like in php

```
$_Files['name_offile_field_of_your_choice]
$_POST['some_field_other_than_file]
```